# FTP passive mode with easyFTP

Tags: java, ftp

I am using [easyFTP](https://github.com/linkindrew/easyFTP) for upload file in android.this liberty  for transfer use active mode now want use passive mode but don't find passive mode

```
ftp = new easyFTP();
ftp.connect("ip", "user", "pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `easyFTP.getFtpClient()` to get an underlying instance of Apache [`FTPClient` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). And call [`enterLocalPassiveMode()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode()) on that:

```
ftp.getFtpClient().enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

---

*Though I do not really see the point of using `easyFTP`. It adds hardly anything to `FTPClient` functionality. Use `FTPClient` directly.*